# ERROR: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-context, android-sensors, ime, sensormanager

I am trying to implement MovementDetector in my soft keyboard, but I get this error. When I compile my code everything works, but when I start using my keyboard it shows error in logcat. Here is my code:

```
public class MovementDetector implements SensorEventListener {

protected final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
private Sensor accelerometer;
private SensorManager mSensorMgr;
public static Context mContext;
float [] history = new float[2];
public static String [] direction = {"NONE","NONE"};

private MovementDetector(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}

private static MovementDetector mInstance;

public static MovementDetector getInstance() {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new MovementDetector(mContext);
        mInstance.init();
    }
    return mInstance;
}

private HashSet<Listener> mListeners = new HashSet<MovementDetector.Listener>();

private void init() {
    mSensorMgr = (SensorManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    accelerometer = mSensorMgr.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION);
}

public void start() {
    mSensorMgr.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

public void stop() {
    mSensorMgr.unregisterListener(this);
}

public void addListener(Listener listener) {
    mListeners.add(listener);
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION) {

        float x = event.values[0];
        float y = event.values[1];
        float z = event.values[2];

        float xChange = history[0] - event.values[0];
        float yChange = history[1] - event.values[1];

        history[0] = event.values[0];
        history[1] = event.values[1];

        float diff = (float) Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y + z * z);
        if (diff > 0.5)
            if (xChange > 2){
                direction[0] = "LEFT";
            }else if (xChange < -2){
                direction[0] = "RIGHT";
            }

            if (yChange > 2){
                direction[1] = "DOWN";
            }else if (yChange < -2){
                direction[1] = "UP";
            }

        for (Listener listener : mListeners) {
            listener.onMotionDetected(event, diff);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

}

public interface Listener {
    void onMotionDetected(SensorEvent event, float acceleration);
}
```

}

I get error in this line:

```
mSensorMgr = (SensorManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
```

I start MovementDetector in OnCreateInputView() and stop it in OnDestory(), but this is not the problem. The problem is in MovementDetector class. Can someone please tell me what should i do and what I did wrong? Thanks in advance. Really need this MovementDetector to work.

Comment: Your `mContext ` variable is null. Its not being passed properly in the constructor. Put a break point in the constructor and see if you're getting a value there.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Android Development and I haven't learned a lot about Context and Instance. Here is what I have tried, but it didn't work: `private MovementDetector(Context context) {
        if(context != null) {
            mContext = context;
        }
    }`

Comment: That is ok. But make sure you're passing the `context` to the constructor properly. Check the place where you initialize the `MovementDetector` cariable.

Comment: This is where I initialize it `mSensorMgr = (SensorManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);` and the error is in that line

Comment: I am asking about the initialization of `MovementDetector` class. It'd look something like `mMovementDetector = new MovementDetector();`. Could you paste that line?

Comment: This code is in main class that extends InputMethodService: `MovementDetector.getInstance().start();
            MovementDetector.getInstance().addListener(new MovementDetector.Listener() {/*detection of the movement*/}` and nowhere else I can find `new MovementDetector`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so finally based upon your inputs from above in the comments, I've been able to identify the issue. It seems that `MovementDetector` class is using the singleton design pattern.

To get the instance of the `MovementDetector` you are using the following code

```
MovementDetector.getInstance()
```

and the `getInstance()` method in MovementDetector is defined as

```
public static MovementDetector getInstance() {
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new MovementDetector(mContext);
        mInstance.init();
    }
    return mInstance;
}
```

Now when this code (`getInstance()`) is called for the very first time, the `mInstance` is null, so it instantiates it.

```
mInstance = new MovementDetector(mContext);
```

But the problem above is that `mContext` is null and that is why you're getting the error! To solve your problem, you should pass the [`context`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) to the `getInstance()` method. It should look like something like this.

```
public static MovementDetector getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new MovementDetector(context);
            mInstance.init();
        }
        return mInstance;
    }
```

And wherever you're calling this method `getInstance()` it should change to something like

```
MovementDetector.getInstance(context).start();
```

Comment: Glad I could help! Happy coding :)